# Are there any examples of well designed applications on iPad with 3 column layouts?

Tags: layout, ios, ipad, grid, apple

I'm designing an iPad application and had an interest in a 3 column interface with 3 tableviews across the screen horizontally and I was wondering if this interface has been done anywhere well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitpad, a news app, has a nice three column layout. Feedly uses a three column layout on the bottom half of the Featured screen. Also, slightly tangential to your question, both NPR and Taptu both utilize very interesting three row layouts you might also want to checkout.